# All fontFamily not vertically in middle of <span> in HTML

Tags: html, fonts, font-family

I am generating HTML from Fabric JS JSON.

But certain font families are not rendering in the middle of <span> elements.

Font Not rendering as Expected : Choko Pain , Nurjan, Eczar Extra Bold, VarianeScript

As I shown in Below Roboto font render at Middle of Span in HTML but chokoPlain font render at bottom of span.

I want all FontFamily to render in the middle of the span, just like in FabricJS canvas.

```
<html id="#html">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




    <style type="text/css">
        body,
        p,
        div {
            font-weight: 100 !important;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #chart-Container,
        .canvas-container,
        .hidden-div,
        #cropCanvas,
        #curveCanvas {
            display: none;
        }

        #div {
            box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
            font-weight: normal;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative !important;
        }

        .clip-text {
            -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div">
        <span id="chart-Container"></span>
    </div>

    <canvas id="curveCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cropCanvas"></canvas>
    <div class="hidden-div"></div>
    <script>

        var json = {
            "background_json": {
                "background_image": "",
                "background_color": "#ffde59"
            },
            "sample_image": "",
            "height": 800,
            "width": 650,
            "display_height": 800,
            "display_width": 650,
            "display_size_type": "px",
            "user_template_category": "Flyer",
            "is_featured": 0,
            "is_portrait": 0,
            "page_id": 614458,
            "page_index": 1,
            "canvasJSON": {
                "objects": [
                    {
                        "type": "i-text",
                        "originX": "left",
                        "originY": "top",
                        "left": 15,
                        "top": 289,
                        "width": 310,
                        "height": 38,
                        "fill": "#ffffff",
                        "stroke": "#ffffff",
                        "strokeWidth": 0,
                        "strokeDashArray": null,
                        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
                        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
                        "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
                        "scaleX": 1,
                        "scaleY": 1,
                        "angle": 0,
                        "flipX": false,
                        "flipY": false,
                        "opacity": 1,
                        "shadow": {
                            "color": "#000000",
                            "blur": 0,
                            "offsetX": 0,
                            "offsetY": 0,
                            "affectStroke": false
                        },
                        "visible": true,
                        "clipTo": null,
                        "backgroundColor": "",
                        "fillRule": "nonzero",
                        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
                        "transformMatrix": null,
                        "skewX": 0,
                        "skewY": 0,
                        "text": "ADD HEADING TEXT",
                        "fontSize": 34,
                        "fontWeight": "bold",
                        "fontFamily": "Roboto-Regular",
                        "fontStyle": "",
                        "lineHeight": 1.16,
                        "textDecoration": "",
                        "textAlign": "left",
                        "textBackgroundColor": "#16cee7",
                        "charSpacing": 0,
                        "customSourceType": "text_json",
                        "id": 472947,
                        "bg_image": "",
                        "texture_image": "",
                        "excludeFromExport": false,
                        "_controlsVisibility": {
                            "tl": true,
                            "tr": true,
                            "br": true,
                            "bl": true,
                            "ml": false,
                            "mt": false,
                            "mr": false,
                            "mb": false,
                            "mtr": true
                        },
                        "isLocked": false,
                        "styles": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "i-text",
                        "originX": "left",
                        "originY": "top",
                        "left": 354,
                        "top": 289,
                        "width": 285,
                        "height": 38,
                        "fill": "#ffffff",
                        "stroke": "#ffffff",
                        "strokeWidth": 0,
                        "strokeDashArray": null,
                        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
                        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
                        "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
                        "scaleX": 1,
                        "scaleY": 1,
                        "angle": 0,
                        "flipX": false,
                        "flipY": false,
                        "opacity": 1,
                        "shadow": {
                            "color": "#000000",
                            "blur": 0,
                            "offsetX": 0,
                            "offsetY": 0,
                            "affectStroke": false
                        },
                        "visible": true,
                        "clipTo": null,
                        "backgroundColor": "",
                        "fillRule": "nonzero",
                        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
                        "transformMatrix": null,
                        "skewX": 0,
                        "skewY": 0,
                        "text": "ADD HEADING TEXT",
                        "fontSize": 34,
                        "fontWeight": "bold",
                        "fontFamily": "ChokoPlain",
                        "fontStyle": "",
                        "lineHeight": 1.16,
                        "textDecoration": "",
                        "textAlign": "left",
                        "textBackgroundColor": "#14e8f8",
                        "charSpacing": 0,
                        "customSourceType": "text_json",
                        "id": 546246,
                        "bg_image": "",
                        "texture_image": "",
                        "font_path": "fonts/choko_plain.otf",
                        "excludeFromExport": false,
                        "_controlsVisibility": {
                            "tl": true,
                            "tr": true,
                            "br": true,
                            "bl": true,
                            "ml": false,
                            "mt": false,
                            "mr": false,
                            "mb": false,
                            "mtr": true
                        },
                        "isLocked": false,
                        "styles": {}
                    }
                ],
                "background": "#ffde59"
            }

        };
        var curveTextJson;

        $(function () {
            var elements = [];
            var div_el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
            div_el.style.height = json.height;
            div_el.style.width = json.width;
            document.body.style.fontFamily = "aAidilfitri";
            if (json.background_json && json.background_json.background_color != "") {
                div_el.style.backgroundColor = json.background_json.background_color;
            }
            div_el.style.position = "absolute";


            // For iText json data
            if (json.canvasJSON && json.canvasJSON.objects.length > 0) {
                var font_array = [];
                json.canvasJSON.objects.forEach((text, index) => {
                    if (text.type == "i-text") {
                        let { left, top, height, width } = text;
                        let isfontFamily = false;
                        let totalTopChoko;
                        let total_height;

                        if (left > json.width) {
                            total_height = (left - json.width) * 2;
                        }
                        else if (top > json.height) {
                            total_height = ((top - json.height) * 2) + 2;
                        }



                        let iText = document.createElement("p");
                        iText.style.left = `${(left > json.width) ? json.width : left}px`; //`${left || 0}`
                        iText.style.top = `${top > json.height ? json.height : top}px`;  //`${top || 0}px`; 
                        iText.style.height = `${(left > json.width) || (top > json.height) ? height - total_height : height}px`;
                        iText.style.width = width;
                        iText.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
                        iText.style.opacity = text.opacity;
                        iText.style.position = "absolute";
                        iText.style.display = "flex";
                        iText.style.userSelect = "none";



                        // Load Font
                        if (!font_array.includes(text.fontFamily)) {
                            font_array.push(text.fontFamily);


                            let path = "";
                            if (text.font_path && text.font_path != '') {
                                path = text.font_path.replaceAll(' ', '%20');
                            }

                            let font_path = text.font_path ? 'https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/6c2c79efb5287200bdd8ca03a187db5d.ttf' : 'https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/03613b6e684c3d8421fc15ef7e0214b5.ttf';

                            new FontFace(text.fontFamily, `url(${font_path})`)
                                .load()
                                .then(function (loadedFace) {
                                    document.fonts.add(loadedFace);
                                })
                                .catch(function (error) {
                                    console.log(error, "error");
                                });
                        }

                        let isMultiLine = text.text.includes("\n");
                        let hasOverline = text.textDecoration.includes("overline");
                        let hasShadow =
                            text.shadow.offsetX !== 0 || text.shadow.offsetY !== 0 || text.shadow.blur !== 0;
                        let hasBGColor = text.textBackgroundColor && text.textBackgroundColor !== "";
                        let isPattern = text.fill.type === "pattern";
                        let isGradiant = text.fill.type === "linear" || text.fill.type === "radial";
                        let hasStrokeWidth = text.strokeWidth > 0;

                        // General

                        let style;

                        let iTextHolder = document.createElement("span");
                        // Inital Styling
                        let otherText = text.text;
                        let regex = /</g;
                        let matches = otherText.match(regex);

                        if (matches !== null) {
                            let convertedText = otherText.replace(regex, '&lt;');
                            iTextHolder.innerHTML = convertedText;
                        }
                        else {
                            iTextHolder.innerText = otherText;
                        }


                        style = `
                                        display: flex;
                                        align-items: center;
                                        height: ${(left > json.width) || (top > json.height) ? height - total_height : height}px;
                                        font-family: ${text.fontFamily};
                                        font-size: ${Math.round(text.fontSize)}px;
                                        ${text.fontStyle !== "" ? `font-style: ${text.fontStyle};` : ""}
                                        ${text.fontWeight !== ""
                                ? `font-weight: ${text.fontWeight};`
                                : ""
                            }
                                        ${!isGradiant && !isPattern && text.fill !== ""
                                ? `color: ${text.fill};`
                                : ""
                            }   
                                        
                                        line-height: ${text.lineHeight};
                                        transform: rotate(${text.angle}deg);
                                        transform-origin: top left;
                                        letter-spacing: ${text.charSpacing / 1000}em;
                                        margin: 0;
                                        margin-top: 0px !important;
                                        padding-right: ${(Math.round(text.fontSize) * 10) / 60}px;
                                    `;




                        // Text align and white sapce
                        if (text.textAlign == "justify") {
                            style += `text-align-last: justify;`;
                        }
                        if (/\s/g.test(text.text)) {
                            style += `white-space: pre;`;
                        }


                        // Background Color Layer
                        if (hasBGColor) {
                            let istop = false;
                            let totalTop;

                            if (text.fontFamily === "ChokoPlain" || text.fontFamily === "Choko Plain") {
                                istop = true;
                                totalTop = (text.height - text.fontSize) + 2;
                            }

                            if (text.fontFamily === "DelinquentCaps") {
                                istop = true;
                                totalTop = (text.height - text.fontSize);
                            }

                            let bgColor = document.createElement("span");
                            bgColor.setAttribute(
                                "style",
                                `
                                                position: absolute;
                                                transform: rotate(${text.angle}deg);
                                                transform-origin: top left;
                                                height: 100%;
                                                width: 100%;
                                                background-color: ${text.textBackgroundColor};
                                            `
                            );
                            // top: ${text.textBackgroundColor && !text.fill.type ? '3px' : '0px'}
                            // top: ${istop ? totalTop : '0'}
                            iText.append(bgColor);
                        }
                        iTextHolder.setAttribute("style", style);
                        style += `position: absolute;`;
                        iText.append(iTextHolder);
                        iText.setAttribute("data-id", text.id);
                        elements[text.index ? text.index : index] = iText;

                    }
                });
            }


            if (elements.length > 0) {
                elements.forEach((el) => {
                    div_el.appendChild(el);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROUOw.png)xpected Output

[HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRY0w.png)
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkhO5.png)

[Higher Height output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scb5u.png)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Tried to create a working snippet from the above but it does nothing.

Comment: If you have this problem with specific fonts, it's most likely and issue built-in to the font - like an x-baseline that is incorrectly set, making the text look like it was placed lower. Better try this with larger wrappers first so you can see whether it's being aligned by the box or by the font, as you have so little margin it's hard to tell. This can still "technically" be as centered as the renderer can deduce.

Comment: Please check images  so you can get more Idea about what I am expecting.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkhO5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRY0w.png

Comment: I have seen your images - make the height higher and see if the font stills sticks "to the bottom" or whether it's not. If it's still centered (but off), then its probably in the font file. Fonts can have incorrect settings as well, and it can mess with how centers are computed.

Comment: When I increase the height, the font rendering behavior remains the same.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scb5u.png